# R sum rows in a telecommunication matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I have a big matrix df with a length of over 3000 rows. I am programming in R. It looks like this:

```
df:   person1    person2    calls
         1        3          5
         1        4          7
         2        11         6
         3        1          5
         3        2          1
         3        4          13
```

and so on.

What i want to do is to get the total number of calls that each person made and received in two matrices. This would look like this:

```
 calls:      person   madecalls             received:   person    receivedcalls
               1          12                              1            5
               2           6                              2            1
               3           19                             3            5
                                                          4            20
                                                          11           6
```

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `aggregate` function:

```
made.calls <- aggregate(df$calls, by = list(person = df$person1), fun = sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

.....`plyr` way:

```
library(plyr)

ddply(df, .(person1), function(x) data.frame( madecalls = sum(x$calls) )
```